# Imported raster file becomes grainy/distorted when plotting with R

Tags: raster, r, graphics

**Note: edited post for clarity, April 3rd**

I'm pretty new to GIS stuff, and I'm trying to incorporate some map rasters into my plots of sampling locations in R.

I've got a fairly high-resolution geo-referenced .tif of the area I want to plot. ([Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/km8usaxqranpetv/657_69_50.tif?dl=0) to the original image file) Using the *raster* package, I've tried importing it and plotting it in true color:

```
map1 <- stack("filename.tif")
png("myplot.png", width=5000, height=5000)
plotRGB(map1)
dev.off()
```

However, it comes out insanely grainy, both in the R plotting window and when exported as an image file. What's going wrong? Below is a before-and-after comparison.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A high-resolution image plotted in a small frame probably will generate this kind of visual issue. Check properties, does the loaded file have the same rows/columns? If so, is just a visual representation issue

Comment: The same rows/columns as what, sorry?

Comment: Same number of rows/columns as the file before loading it

Comment: Right -- the original image is 5000x5000 pixels, and when loaded into R, the raster object has 5000 rows and columns. But the image looks compressed even when I export it to an image file that is also 5000x5000 pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel image (you don't tell us the resolution, but I'd call this fairly high-res) and then plot it on screen, your screen might only show 1,000 x 1,000 pixels. So something has to be done.

The easiest thing for software to do is to transform from the 1,000x1,000 space to the 10,000x10,000 space and pick the nearest pixel. This might have the effect you are seeing since smooth variation is likely to get sampled out.

The more complex alternative is to transform from the 1,000x1,000 space to the location in the 10,000x10,000 space and take a few pixels near there and average, and display the average pixel back in the 1,000x1,000 grid. This results in a smoother image but its not "honest" to the data since its showing averages. Also this might not be appropriate if you have categorical data, since you'll get values in between the category integers.

With `raster` you can use `plotRGB(r, interpolate=TRUE)` to do some smoothing. It might improve your image quality in this case. The equivalent in the `terra` package is the `smooth=TRUE` argument to its `plotRGB` function.

I don't think either package give you any control over the smoothing, if you get fussy about it then you may need to use one of the transform functions in the packages to do a precise conversion to a new resolution.

Also, and if you read the help for `plotRGB` you'll see this, there is a default limit on the number of pixels that it will plot, irrespective of the resolution of the output device. It is set to 500,000, which is roughly 800x600 or 700x700, so even if you use a `png` device with 5,000 x 5,000 pixels, `plotRGB` will by default only sample 500,000 of the points in your image and then either plot the nearest neighbour pixels by default:

[image]

or add `interpolate=TRUE` to get a bit of smearing:

[image]

but that is still only 500,000 pixels from your data. To get something more like all the pixels from your image, set `maxpixels` to something larger than the number of pixels in your image (5,000 x 5,000) to get a PNG that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! The original resolution is 5000x5000. Even when I export the plot at the same resolution, it still gets grainy in exactly the same way as the example I posted.

Comment: What do you mean "export the plot"? What's your code for the export? Can you upload your image somewhere we can download it?

Comment: I mean export it from R to a PGN file, as opposed to plotting it directly in R's tiny plotting window. I added a link to the file and some additional code in the question post.

Comment: You're also hitting the `maxpixels` limit of `plotRGB`. See my edits.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it, thanks!